# Is there a way to remove a whole property from a js object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I presume this is an odd question but I have to ask..

If I have a js object that looks like this:

```
$scope.obj1 = {
    "name":"John",
    "number":"Eleven",
    "color":"Red"
}
```

Is there a way to remove an entire property? **without re-assigning values to a new object**..  So if I want to get rid of `"number":"Eleven",` I would like the object to look like this...

```
$scope.obj1 = {
    "name":"John",
    "color":"Red"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"If I have a json object [...]"* [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: I am aware of that... I wrote this small tidbit as a string to ask a question... thanks anyways.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript has a [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
delete $scope.obj1.number
```

Comment: In case you were wondering about your binding close vote: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-superpowers

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you totally read my mind with that one...you mods *are* superheros.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You really should have announced this somewhere. It caught me totally off-guard and I thought it was bug. (I like it, but it's surprising).

Comment: @FelixKling: Now in the side bar.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I [was surprised too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254615/whoa-wait-what-no-consensus-needed) :D

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the qucik answer. I don't know why I omitted to remember this.

Comment: By the way,, it would be a lot easier to not write duplicate questions if results of what I asked for appeared in search results :/